# How to make d3 pages load dynamically with flask/jinja

Tags: javascript, python, d3.js, flask, jinja2

I'm currently working in a project where we are using flask, where jinja drives the frontend via blocks, with the goal to create a sort of dynamic page. However, I am currently stuck on how to refer to new pages/components without having to refresh them upon navigation.

For instance, in the current version, if I navigate "forward" via a button press on the page, the new page (static html) loads, but nothing shows, if I then refresh the page, the content loads properly for that page. If I instead try to load a page with static content, such as text, it loads properly right of the bat.

My theory thus far is that this is due to that the D3 graphs that we are loading on the button press aren't loading quick enough to be called right away, and as such some kind of listener or delay should be implemented.

The question however, is how this should be properly implemented.

In the current state of the application we have reversed to having a href link referring to a page route in flask. We have tried to put a "done" checker to see if the content loading function runs, but without success. However, we may have implemented the function incorrectly.

In the first html template:

```
{% extends "index.html" %}
{% block content %}

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <h1 class="mt-4">Simple Sidebar</h1>
    <canvas id="chart_1", height=40></canvas>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="comment">Comment:</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment"></textarea>
    </div>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><a href=" {{ url_for('step_2') }} ">Next</a></button>
    <script type="text/javascript">


    </script>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/chart_1.js') }}"></script>


</body>

{% endblock content %}
```

Route to next template in Flask:

```
@app.route("/step_2")
def step_2():
    return render_template("chart_2.html", methods = ['GET'])
```

I don't get any error messages, as it works, but not as intended.

Comment: Do you have your JS wrapped in an event listener for page load, e.g. [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event)?